# Contact form is not sending

Tags: php, html, sendmail

I had it working for a minute and I'm not sure what I did to stop it from working. It still takes me to the other page on submit but my email gets absolutely no activity.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact_form" action="sendemail.php" method="post">
    <p><label>Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield" value="" />
    </label></p>

    <p><label>Email: <br />
         <input type="text" name="email" class="textfield" value="" />
    </label></p>

    <p><label>Phone Number: <br />
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="textfield" value="" />
    </label></p>

    <p><label>Detail: <br />
        <textarea name="detail" class="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
    </label></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$detail = $_REQUEST['detail'];

$message = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone Number: $phone\nDetail: $detail" ;

mail( "myemail@gmail.com", "You have recieved a message", "Information Requested:\n\n$message", "From: $email") ;

header( "location: http://mywebsite.com/thanks.html" );

?>
```

Comment: It's going to your spam folder

Comment: Do you receive any error message?

Comment: Do you have a mail server set up?

Comment: Do you read the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Many servers have an I/O email limit. It happened me once while trying the code. Maybe it's just this or – as Austin said – maybe the message is sent to the SPAM folder of your email address.

Try to check you webserver log to see if it contains more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the header and do some improvements, try to use this code:

```
// As you know that you form uses POST method, you can use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST
$name   = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$phone  = $_POST['phone'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];

// Headers
$headers  = "From: =?utf-8?B?".base64_encode ('Sender Name')."?= <sender@email.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

// As the content is HTML, you shoud use <br /> instead of \n to break line
$message = "Name: $name<br />Email: $email<br />Phone Number: $phone<br />Detail: $detail" ;

// Trying to send the message
if ( mail('to@email.com', "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode('Message subject')."?=", $message, $headers) )
    header( "location: http://mywebsite.com/thanks.html" );
else
    echo 'Message fail';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your junk/spam folder. If the message isn't there, try this code:

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$detail = $_REQUEST['detail'];

$message = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone Number: $phone\nDetail: $detail" ;

var_dump( mail( "myemail@gmail.com", "You have recieved a message", "Information Requested:\n\n$message", "From: $email") );

//header( "location: http://mywebsite.com/thanks.html" );
?>
```

If the mail was successfully sent, it will return `bool(true)`, otherwise it will return `bool(false)` if it failed.

Also, make double sure that the email address is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors? Use `ini_set('display_errors', true)` and see.

---

You should change `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`, since the `$_REQUEST` should be used when you don't know where data coming from (GET, POST or COOKIE). We see the data coming from POST, because you sepecified form's method as POST.

You should also check if those variables are set by using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

---

@[Marcio Simao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11496422/1494505)
 
Headers are not necessary for script to work. It's optional parameter.

Comment: You will increase a lot the chances of your message go to the spam folder, so it's highly recommended to define them

Answer (score 0):

may be this is because of HTML if it show you `bool(true)` in `var_dump()`...

try to put out your input fields from label... usually label is used for the coming field.. don't put the field under the label tag... like this:

```
<p><label>Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield" value="" />
</label></p>
```

but first check your php code with `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
$name = $_POST['name'];
... other info
$message = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone Number: $phone\nDetail: $detail";
mail( "myemail@gmail.com", "You have recieved a message", "Information Requested:\n\n$message", "From: $email") ;
   header( "location: http://mywebsite.com/thanks.html" );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi kindly check your mail() if its working.

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
  // Working
}
```

if not kindly do the standard formatting of mail function

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$detail = $_REQUEST['detail'];


$subject = "Subject";
$headers = "From: \"".$youremail." ".$youremail."\" <".$youremail.">\n"; 
$headers .= "To: \"".$email."\" <".$email.">\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: <".$email.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";    

$message = "Your Message here!";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
   // success
}
```